# gradient at the minimum in fmin_l_bfgs_b

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, gradient

I am using fmin_l_bfgs_b for a bounded minimization on 4 parameters. 
I would like to inspect the gradient at the minimum of the cost function and for this I call the d['grad'] parameter as described in the documentation of fmin_l_bfgs_b. My problem is that d['grad'] is an array of size 4 looking like:

'grad': array([  8.38440428e-05,  -5.72697445e-04,   3.21875859e-03,
        -2.21115926e+00])

I would expect it to be a single value close to zero. Does this have something to do with the number of the parameters I am using for the minimization (4)..? Not what I would expect but  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is the gradient of the cost function with respect to each parameter, in turn.

To picture it, suppose there were only two parameters, x and y. The cost function is a surface z as a function of x and y.
The optimization is finding a minimum point on that surface.
That's where the gradients with respect to both x and y are zero (or close to it).
If either gradient is not zero, you are not at a minimum, and you would descend further.

As a further point, you could well be interested in the curvature, or second derivative, because high curvature means a narrow (precise) minimum, while low curvature means a nearly flat minimum, with very uncertain estimates.
The second derivative in the x,y case would not be a 2-vector, but a 2x2-matrix (called a "Hessian", just to snow your friends).
You might want to think about why it's a 2x2-matrix.

Comment: If the optimization problem is bounded (as is possible with L-BFGS-B), the gradient is not necessarily zero at the solution.

Comment: @pv: If the optimization is bounded, that means at the boundary the dimensionality of the problem is reduced. You discard the parameter whose boundary you are at. For each remaining parameter, the gradient has to approach zero. But you are right, for each parameter whose boundary you are at, the gradient is not zero. In practice at our company, we have several different optimizers, and if there are boundaries we use log or logit transformation of the parameters, rather than wrestle with bounded optimization.